# Removing array-objects from DisplayList

Tags: actionscript-3, displayobject

I'm working on a game for the iPhone using flash, and since memory is crucial i want to clean up displayObjects not needed. All the objects i need to delete is MovieClips taken from some array to another using splice(). Here is the code.

```
public function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
```

{
   randomNr = Math.random();

```
if ( randomNr > 0.9 )
```

{
   var newFriend:Friend = new Friend( randomX, -15 );
   newFriend.cacheAsBitmap = true;
   army.push(newFriend);
   addChild(newFriend);
   }

for (var i:int = 0; i < army.length;i++)
    {
    army[i].y += 3;

```
if (avatar.hitTestObject(army[i])) 
{
 mood = false;
 TweenLite.to(army[i], .3, {x:308, y:458, scaleX:.7, scaleY:.7, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:fadeFace, onCompleteParams:[army[i],mood]});  
 deleted.push(army.splice(i,1));
}
```

}
    }

```
private function cleanUp(e:MouseEvent):void
```

{
    var totalDel:int = deleted.length;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < totalDel ;i++)
    {
    removeChild(deleted[i]);
    }
    trace(totalDel + " Dele from deleted");
   }

My problem is that i get an error when trying to use the CleanUp function.
I can trace all objects in the array and they show as [object Friend], but when trying to remove then from the displayList i get this Error:  Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@2c11309 to flash.display.DisplayObject.

Might be the wrong method im using!? Need some guidance please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend coder ended up handing me the perfect solution:

```
private function cleanUp(arr:Array):void
        {
            var toDelete:DisplayObject;
            var totalDel:int = 0;

            while(arr.length >0)
            {
                toDelete = arr[0];
                toDelete.parent.removeChild(toDelete);
                arr.shift();
                totalDel++
            }
            //trace(totalDel + "deleted from array " + arr.length + " left");
        }
```

This way all objects gets deleted without any collapsing the array, which is exactly what i needed... Hope this will help someone withe the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting each "Friend" as a Display Object:

```
var totalDel:int = deleted.length; 
for(var i:int = 0; i < totalDel ;i++) {
var toDelete:DisplayObject = deleted[i] as DisplayObject;
removeChild(toDelete);
trace(totalDel + "Dele from deleted");
}
```

Comment: Apparently this makes the object value null, so i get a new error when trying to delete it.

Comment: Hm...it's making "toDelete" null? when are you calling the cleanUp function?

Comment: solved the problem with the while-loop posted above :) thx for helping out